# Displaying dates from a List C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display dates from a `list` within a `ListBox`. To do this I am trying to bind the `list` to a `listbox`.

Here is the code for my driver class.

```
public class Driver
{
    private string name;
    private string occupation;
    private DateTime dateOfBirth;
    private List<DateTime> dateOfClaim;

    public Driver(string name, string occupation, DateTime dateOfBirth, List<DateTime> dateOfClaim)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.occupation = occupation;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.dateOfClaim = dateOfClaim;
    }

    public string DriverName
    {
        get{ return name; }
        set{ name = value; }
    }

    public string DriverOccupation
    {
        get { return occupation; }
        set { occupation = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DriverDateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { dateOfBirth = value; }
    }

    public List<DateTime> DriverDateOfClaim
    {
        get { return dateOfClaim; }
        set { dateOfClaim = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a `button` which allows you to add a `date` for a claim to a driver, up to a maximum of 5 claims. I have a 'temporary' `list` which holds these dates before they are assigned to the `dateOfClaim list` within the `Driver list` as the new driver object has not yet been created.

Here are parts of the code from a form which declares and populates the arraylist.

```
private List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();
private List<DateTime> claimDates = new List<DateTime>();

if (noOfClaims <= 4)
{
    claimDates.Add(dtpAddClaim.Value.Date);
    noOfClaims++;
}

if (noOfDrivers <= 4)
{
    drivers.Add(new Driver(txtName.Text, txtOccupation.Text, dtpDOB.Value.Date, claimDates));
    noOfDrivers++;
}
```

To bind the `dateOfClaim list` to the `listbox` I have tried using the following code, but nothing displays in the listbox.

```
lstClaimDates.DataSource = drivers;
lstClaimDates.DisplayMember = "DriverDateOfClaim";
```

I've tried displaying the dates in a label using the following code, but again, nothing displays which leads me to believe I'm not adding to the `dateOfClaim list` correctly.

```
foreach (DateTime d in drivers[0].driverDateOfClaim)
    label1.Text += d.ToString() + " ";
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All those getters and setters, could be replace with this styling `public DateTime DriverDateOfBirth { get; set; }` and it's a good naming convention to use UpperCase on public properties on the .NET world.

Comment: I don't understand, I copied your code and the dates were added to the label's text.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to display the variable dateOfClaim, but adding the DataTimes to claimDates.  Why two different variables?

Comment: I've had a look through, and I have no idea why it would be working for you but not me. As for the the two lists, the dates are added to claimDates before a new object of Driver is created so they cannot be added to dateOfClaim at that point, so they are held there until the new object is created and then put into the dateOfClaim list.

Comment: Yeah, this is using WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WinForms:**

You need to define the value/field/property that you would like to show in your `listBox`:

```
List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();   
drivers.Add(new Driver("name", "The Earth", DateTime.Now, null));
listBox1.DataSource = drivers;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "drivername";
```

**Update 0:**

Let me know if it is not applicable for you:

```
foreach (var c in drivers[0].driverDateOfClaim)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(c);
}
```

[Magnus Montin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/magnus%20(mm8)/?ws=usercard-mini) is superprogrammer and he [shows another solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21492683-c214-4781-974b-7f241b67fbcc/how-can-i-bind-listbox-to-inner-collection-located-in-a-class?forum=winforms):

```
List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();            
drivers.Add(new Driver("name", "The Earth", DateTime.Now, new List<DateTime>() { 
            DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now, 
        } ));
listBox1.DataSource = drivers[0].driverDateOfClaim;
```

**Update 1:**

```
 List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>();            
 drivers.Add(new Driver("name", "The Earth", DateTime.Now, new List<DateTime>() 
     { 
        DateTime.Now, 
        DateTime.Now, 
        } ));
 foreach (var c in drivers[0].driverDateOfClaim)
 {
   textBox1.Text += " | " + c;
 }
```

Comment: I'm using WinForms so I tried that method and have updated the original post with the new code. The listbox is now dispalying 'MotorInsurance.Driver' with MotorInsurance being the name of the project.

Comment: @Andrew_S,  please see my updated answer. Let me know if it is not applicable for you.

Comment: I've tried the updated answer, but no luck, nothing is displaying in the listbox. Makes me think that since Rariolu said my original code worked for him, my problem is sometime else, but at the minute I have no idea what that could be.

Comment: My problem is that I can't even display the dates in a label using a similar foreach loop

Comment: @Andrew_S please see Update1. I've tested the code at my PC. :)

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot man :) Just gotta change it so that dates can be entered in, but I think I have an idea of how I can do that. Gotta head for a bit now, so I'll give that a shot later.

Answer (score 1):

you can bound them as string, e.g. using Linq

```
lstClaimDates.DataSource = drivers[i].driverDateOfClaim.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToList();
```

should do the job (you can specify your date format in the ToString call)

Comment: When trying this, I get the error 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.'

Comment: you just need to call ToList() at the end, i wrote it without having chance to try it, i edited the answer